# Equal divisors of Weil-pairing

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I try to understand the approach of Silverman to the Weil pairing.
In *The Arithmetic Of Elliptic Curves* he defines the Weil pairing in section III.8 with the help of two divisors:

\begin{equation*}
div(f)= m(T)-m(O) \hspace{0.5cm}\text{and} \hspace{0.5cm}div(g)= [m]^*(T)-[m]^*(O)= \sum_{R\in E[m]}(T'+R)-(R),
\end{equation*}
where $[m]T'=T$ and $E[m]$ being the m-torsion points.

Later on he uses the fact that $f \circ [m]$ and $g^m$ have the same divisors to define the Weil pairing. I can't relate to this fact because I'm not understanding the difference between $[m]^*(T)-[m]^*(O)$ and $m(T)-m(O)$. Can anybody tell me how $[m]^*(T)-[m]^*(O)$ would be defined?

Thank you really much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume the ground field is algebraically closed of characteristic zero.

$[m]^*(T)$ is the pullback of the divisor $(T)$ under the operation $[m]$ which is multiplication by $m$ on the elliptic curve $E$, This means that
$[m]^*(T)=(P_1)+(P_2)+\cdots+(P_{m^2})$ where the $P_i$ are the $m^2$ points
solving $[m]P=T$, that is the $m$-fold addition $P+\cdots+P$ on the elliptic curve
equals $T$. The case $T=O$ gives $[m]^*(O)$. So $[m]^*(T)-[m]^*(O)$
is a rather different beast from $m(T)-m(O)$, which is a sum of $m$ copies of $(T)$
minus a sum of $m$ copies of $(O)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I wonder where Silverman did define this $[m]^*$ operation?

Answer (score 0):

To answer Anuj's question in the comment, this is quite a general construction. If $f:X\to Y$ is any morphism of smooth projective varieties, it induces a pull-back map on divisors,
$$ f^*:\operatorname{Div}(Y)\longrightarrow \operatorname{Div}(X). $$
This map respects linear equivalence, so it induces a map
$$ f^*:\operatorname{Pic}(Y)\longrightarrow \operatorname{Pic}(X). $$
If $X=Y$, and if you manage to identify the linear equivalence class of $f^*X$ as some other divisor that you know in $\operatorname{Pic}(X)$, then you've acquired interesting geometric information relating the map $f$ and the geometry of the variety $X$.

For example, on an abelian variety (a higher dimensional elliptic curve), there is a multiplication-by-$m$ map $[m]:A\to A$, and an enormously useful formula says that
$$ [m]^*D \sim \frac{m^2+1}{2} D + \frac{m^2-1}[-1]^*D. $$